# Deviance of subset of data

Tags: r, regression-testing

Hi I fit a non linear curve and I would like to check the deviance for different segments of the data, because sometimes the curve behaves strangly to fit the data in the different segments which minimizes the deviance at the cost of other segments.

Is there a way to use the deviance function for a subset. Say i have 100 observations and I want to look at the deviance at the bottom 50 and the top 100

```
deviance(reg.model)[1:50], deviance(reg.model)[50:100]
```

or can I use deviance with other data? Otherwise I would have to write my own function to get the sum of squared residuals.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I need to use a data.frame with the right variable name as the second argument for predict. I am not sure if this works for deviance though.

```
predict(reg.model, data.frame(x.var=seq(1,10))
```

would give out of sample predictions for 1 to 10 of my reg model